# Android kotlin сохранение джсон в локальную память

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room, room

соединяю бекенд и андроид с помощью рест.
Хотел бы уточнить следующий ньюанс.

Я получаю список заказов в формате json.

```
{
    "count": 191,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "phone": "+7777777777",
            "name": "name",
            "comment": null,
            "timeFrom": "21:50:00",
            "timeTo": "22:10:00",
            "basketHistory": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Bread",
                    "packaging": "400g",
                    "quantity": "1.000",
                    "units": "ШТ",
                    "price": "56.89",
                    "brgew": "425.000",
                    "gewei": "g",
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "product_id": 2923,
                    "price_discount": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-08-17T13:48:16.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-08-17T13:48:16.000000Z",
                    "path_image": "link9ec782_278421.png"
                },
```

Мой вопрос в следующем, поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь или чего-то не понимаю.
При получении данных я должен их куда-то сохранять. Я нашёл только вариант с Room (если вы предложите аналог и алгоритм работы, я буду рад).

В чём собственно проблема.
Когда я получаю данный джсон через retrofit я пытаюсь засунуть его в ROOM и получаю ошибку из-за поля  basketHistory, потому что **basketHistory является списком** и он не знает как его конвертировать. Единственное что я придумал, то это прописывать это обратно в json и класть его как строку, что мне кажется не верным решением.

```
@Entity
data class Order(

        @SerializedName("id")
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val id: Long,
        @SerializedName("isSendCheque") val isSendCheque: Int,
        @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String,
        @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
        @SerializedName("comment") val comment: String,
        @SerializedName("timeFrom") val timeFrom: String,
        @SerializedName("timeTo") val timeTo: String,
        @SerializedName("basketHistory") val basketHistory: List<Product>,
        @SerializedName("publicOrderId") val publicOrderId: String
)
```

Можете привести мне пример кода для данной проблемы?
Может быть реализовать какие-то связи между таблицами?